# Calling async function & dispatching action from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, es6-promise

I have a React component that dispatches a Redux action from `componentDidMount` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    apiService.fetch().then(success => {
      if (success) {
        this.props.update();
      }
    });
  }
```

The `fetch` method is asynchronous:

```
apiService.fetch = async function() {
  return axios.post('/api/v1/fetch')
    .then(response => {
      this._saveData(response.data);
      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      log.error(`Failed to fetch: ${err}`);
      return false;
    });
}
```

My component is failing to respond to the expected state update from Redux, i.e. the `update()` action is not being dispatched. If I make a change to the `fetch` method like below I *do* see the correct behaviour:

```
apiService.fetch = async function() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

This leads me to believe I am not handling Promises or the async function correctly. For example, one thing I am uncertain about is that I already call `then` on the Axios response inside the `fetch` method, but I also call it in `componentDidMount`; is this correct? Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the API response is a success? Try debug it

Comment: Yes, I have a console.log statement that shows the return value.

Comment: I mean the `success`variable is truth value?